# Apply string format form left to right

Tags: c#, string

How can you make a string that is formatted from a value from left to right?

```
string.Format("{0:00-00-0000}", 123);
```

The above returns as `00-00-0123` I would like it to be `12-30-0000`

Any idea to achieve this?

Comment: You can try some string operations to achieve this!!

Comment: is it some kind of date format you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var padded = long.Parse((123).ToString().PadRight(8, '0'));
string.Format("{0:00-00-0000}", padded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another crazy idea is to do some math

```
int i = 123;
string.Format("{0:00}-{1:00}-{2:0000}", i / 1000000, (i / 10000) % 100, i % 10000);
```